# Playing Audio From Assets Folder

Tags: java, javascript, android, audio, android-activity

I have a html file that I am playing though a webview and it has sound attached.  The html file has javascript with it as well and the java script works but the sound doesnt.  The audio file is a wav file.  Is there somewhere else i am supposed to put the audio file to work?  I read other questions about this problem but they all suggested to put the file in the raw folder, but im using android studio 1.1 and there does not seem to be an option for that.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    WebView wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
    wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    wv.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html");
    wv.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
}
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

}
[image: screenshot]

Comment: Just create the raw folder.

Comment: @GabeSechan take a look at my screenshot...it doesnt allow me to create one..is there a manual way of creating it?

Comment: Yes-  just make the directory in your os.  It's just a folder